# Livewire model binding for casted model attributes

Tags: model-binding, laravel-livewire

I have custom cast in the Laravel model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'price' => CustomCast::class,
];
```

The casted property is an object and thus used in various ways across the application by calling its public methods:

```
$price->getAmount();
$price->convert();
```

If I bind to this model with Livewire the value understandably is not displayed as it requires a method call. The following bind displays `[object Object]`

```
<input wire:model="tx.price" />
```

I tried below to no avail:

```
<input wire:model="tx.price" value={{ $tx->price->getAmount() }} />
```

---

*Is it possible to work around this with Livewire?*

Comment: Does your CustomCast class have a `__toString` method on it?

Comment: It does, but I could investigate if you are implying Livewire is not picking up on it?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of something else - the custom casts must implement the `get()` and `set()` methods (which you might already have), and you can only bind simple types like string and numbers - not arrays or objects. You can't set the value directly on the input element, as Livewire will set it based on the bound value. So the question is, what does the `get()` method of your cast return?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same, did you solve the issue eventually @rock3t?

Comment: Nope, moved away from custom cast.